# How do you get the value of an input inside a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm simply trying to get the value of an input box embedded in a form tag.

For example, this works just fine.

```
<div>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" required />
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="getName()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getName() {
        var name = document.getElementById('fistName').value;
        console.log(name);
    }
</script>
```

This outputs whatever value is enter in the console when the submit button is clicked. However if I put it in a form like below it doesn't return anything.

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="getName()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Does the form tag add some protection? How can I get the value out of an input tag inside a form?

Comment: `fistName` is not equal to `firstName`

Comment: The type submit means submitting the form, so either add a event.preventDefault() or just don't sue the type sumbit on the button, since you're trying to trun js, not submit anything.

Comment: If you have form then it's submited when you click submit and it open the same page if you don't have action.

Answer (score 4):

> it doesn't return anything

Yes it does.

However, since you're *submitting a form*, the page is also immediately refreshing and you're starting over from scratch.

The form isn't "protecting" anything.  The code is doing exactly the same thing in both cases.  But in the second case the `form` is also doing something else (loading the page) before you've physically had time to see the result.

Comment: anyhow i believe it should log in the console right..?

Comment: he can preventDefault the submit event, call his function, and trigger the submit. Pretty bad trick, but works

Comment: @NivasDhina maybe for a split second. Reloading the page usually wipes it out unless you choose to preserve it.

Comment: It is printed in the console for a very short period of time, then the page is reloaded and the console cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

Button of type submit refreshes the page. Also the console gets cleared. So it does output but gets immediately cleared. Try changing the button type to "button". Then it will not refresh the page and you will see the output.